# Matplotlib triangles (plot_trisurf) color and grid

Tags: python, matplotlib, grid, geometry

I'm trying to plot a 3D surface with plot_trisurf like this:

```
xs = NP.array([ 0.00062  0.00661  0.02000  0.01569  0.00487  0.01784])
ys = NP.array([ 0.99999  0.66806  0.50798  0.61230  0.83209  0.86678])
zs = NP.array([-0.24255 -0.42215 -0.31854 -0.77384 -0.77906 -0.98167])

ax=fig.add_subplot(1,2,1, projection='3d')
ax.grid(True)
ax.plot_trisurf(xs, ys, zs, triangles = triangles, alpha = 0.0, color = 'grey')
```

This gives me[image: this plot]

Now I have two problems:

1. The triangles are black, can I change this problem? (It works in 2D
   with triplot with `color = 'grey'` but this doesn't seem to work
   here.
2. (If it is visible) The grid of the 3D plot leaves traces in
   the triangles: it seems like the grid is printed on top of the
   triangles, while I (of course) want the triangles to be plotted on
   top of the grid.

Comment: can you add `xs, ys, zs` to your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change the last line to:

```
ax.plot_trisurf(xs, ys, zs, triangles=triangles, 
                color=(0,0,0,0), edgecolor='Gray')
```

the `color` that you are specifying is used as `facecolor`; if you want to have transparent faces, instead of `alpha=0` pass `color=(r,g,b,0)`; the `0` in the tuple would be the alpha of the facecolor; so it will results in transparent faces;

Comment: Great, thanks!
Do you also have an idea why the grid is plotted on top of the triangles and points?

Comment: i do not have the grids issue on my side, but you may want to try `..., edgecolor='Gray').set_zorder(100)`;